# Unable to configure OrientDB - Java integration on CENTOS7

Tags: java, database, unix, orientdb, centos7

I am trying to create deploy my java web application with orient-db onto a CENTOS7 machine.
Currently I have set up Orient-db on a root privileged users ~/softwares/$ORIENTDB_HOME
The server was successfully set up on the initial config with username and password and startup.
I am now trying to create a remote db to be accessed by my java application using the create database command as follows after running console.sh

> orientdb> CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/test root root plocal

But I am getting the following error

> Creating database [remote:localhost/test] using the storage type
>   [plocal]... Error:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot
>   create the remote storage: test
>
> Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException:
>   Cannot create database 'test'
>           DB name="test"
>           DB name="test"
>
> Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException:
>   Cannot create folders in storage with path
>   /softwares/orientdb-community-2.2.5/orientdb-community-2.2.5/databases/test
>           DB name="test"

I tried CHMODing the .sh bin-directories as well as the $ORIENTDB_HOME/databases directory but the problem persists.

However it allows me to create a db with plocal

> orientdb> CREATE DATABASE plocal:localhost/test root root plocal

But I then get the following error at the java end

`$ java -jar dataloader-jar-with-dependencies.ja`

> 2016-11-24 20:10:41 DEBUG ASMLoader:38 - connecting to:plocal:localhost/asm
>
> 2016-11-24 20:10:41 DEBUG ASMLoader:39 - uname:admin
>
> 2016-11-24 20:10:41 DEBUG ASMLoader:40 - password :admin
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error
>   on opening database 'plocal:localhost/asm'
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:190)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPooled.(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:421)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPooled.(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:417)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.initQueue(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:353)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:114)
>           at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory.(OrientGraphFactory.java:71)
>           at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory.(OrientGraphFactory.java:52)
>           at com.virtusa.asm.repo.ASMLoader.main(ASMLoader.java:42) Caused by:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException:
>   Error on opening database: the engine 'plocal' was not found. URL was:
>   plocal:localhost/asm. Registered engines are: [remote]
>           DB name="plocal:localhost/asm"
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:462)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:170)
>           ... 7 more

Comment: Have you tried creating the folder /databases/test and CHMODing it? Also try with the latest 2.2.13 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you've made a mess with roles and permissions. Which system user did you use to unpack OrientDB? And which one did you use to run it as a standalone server?
I"m asking because you're able to create a database with the console in plocal (plocal means embedded). 
I guess you extracted the tar using root and then started the server from a regular user login shell.

In the last step you are pointing to a wrong db address: `connecting to:plocal:localhost/asm`

If you are accessing a db in plocal (embedded), just use `plocal:/path/to/db/folder`.

If you are accessing a db provided by a standalone server, use `remote:SERVER_ADDRESS/db_NAME`